# ReactJS: Rendering the state separately and not as an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I ended up pulling off what I wanted. However, it's giving me an array of the state instead of rendering each one separately. This is probably very simple and I'm more than likely over-complicating it but hey, any help would be nice.

[Here's what I currently am dealing with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H61rt.gif)

And here's a better example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4STTN.gif

And lastly here's probably the best overview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOyYh.jpg

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false,
    }
  }

  ws = new WebSocket(URL)

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('connected')
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = e => {
      const tbox = JSON.parse(e.data);
      if(tbox.data && tbox.data.length > 0){
      this.setState({
          data : this.state.data.concat(tbox.data[0]),
        })
      }
    }

    this.ws.onclose = () => {
      console.log('disconnected')
      this.setState({
        ws: new WebSocket(URL),
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
   let { data } = this.state;

   const chatBox = data.map(item => {
    return (
      <List
      key={item.id}
      dataSource={this.state.data}
      renderItem={item => (
        <List.Item >
          <List.Item.Meta
            avatar={<Avatar size="large" icon="user" />}
            title={<div><a href="https://example.com">{item.user}</a> {item.date}</div>}
            description={item.message}
          />
        </List.Item>
      )}
    >
    </List>
    )
  })

   return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {chatBox}
        </div>
```

I'm trying to loop through the state and render each message separately

Comment: Is your issue that the messages are each being rendered twice?

Comment: @NickFriedman multiple times, yes. here's a better example: https://i.imgur.com/WLDkbOb.gif

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. First thing I would check is to log your `data` and make sure that there's only 1 copy of the data. Second I would ask you to post the code for the `List` component

Comment: @NickFriedman take a look at this! https://imgur.com/a/zintqTA

Comment: Is it possible you keep getting all the data again and are appending it to your state which gives you multiples copies in your state? If that's your issue you need to figure out a way to only add the *new* data to your state

Comment: or you can simply replace your state every time instead of using `concat`, this will be simpler however is less performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to loop through `this.state.data[]` because you are already setting data source to `antd` `<List>` component. `antd` `List` component handles collection of objects for us.
This would be the code for rendring your `this.state.data`:

```
const chatBox = <List dataSource={this.state.data}
      renderItem={item => (
        <List.Item >
          <List.Item.Meta
            avatar={<Avatar size="large" icon="user" />}
            title={<div><a href="https://example.com">{item.user}</a> 
            {item.date}</div>}
            description={item.message}
          />
        </List.Item>
      )}
    >
    </List>;
```

you can have a look at these links :

- https://stackblitz.com/run
- https://ant.design/components/list/

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!